# Aptitude or something else?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux in general. I've also already managed to bork a few installs.

Anyways, my question is whether I should stick with a package manager like Aptitude or is there something better? I checked out debfoster thinking it was the best thing in the world, and then I went to Aptitude once I figured out it was depreciated.
Though I'm basically looking for something that is going to keep track of packages I install and they're dependencies, and uninstall everything in the case that I don't want that package instead of just keeping the dependencies on my system.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You say you're "pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux" in general. Then you ask whether you should stick with a package manager like Aptitude. But how and why did you have Aptitude installed? It doesn't come by default on any official flavor of Ubuntu, AFAIK. Just asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default package manager in ubuntu, `apt` (install a package with `sudo apt-get install PACKAGE`) does this itself.

For example, if package `foobar` depended on packages `foo` and `bar` and you removed `foobar`, it **wont** be *automatically* removed but `foo` and `bar` will be removed when you run the command `sudo apt-get autoremove`

It should be noted that `apt-get autoremove` will only remove an auto installed dependency if no other packages need it, to prevent breaking your system

`aptitude` is a good tool if you want to read detailed info about a package (without installing it) and it's dependencies or if you are unsure of a package's name and want to search for it

Comment: Alrighty, I have tried that before... Though I had a PS2 Emulator that installed 100+ dependencies and autoremove took none of them off.

Comment: @Keki What package was this? Did you install it with `apt-get`?

Comment: I did not, I installed it with Syaptic Package Manager... Guessing that's where the problem lies?

Comment: Could be, but Synaptic uses `apt` as a backend, it just provides a graphical way to search for packages

Comment: Oh, and it was PCSX2.

Comment: @Keki That may be because that other packages depend on the dependencies `pcsx2` installed. `apt-get autoremove` will only remove an auto installed dependency if no other packages need it, to prevent breaking your system

Comment: Aye, I also just removed Aptitude to test this and it all seems t work. That must have been what happened, thanks for the help.

Comment: It did, says I can click it in three minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **apt-get** on Ubuntu. Look at [Community HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).

Other package managers:

- **aptitude** (same as **apt-get**, just a bit less friendly)
- [**npm**](http://npmjs.org) - Node package manager
- **gem** - Ruby package manager
- [**bower**](http://bower.io) - package manager for the web
- [**component**](http://component.io) - another package manager for (better) web

Comment: Why is `aptitude` less friendly than `apt-get`?

Comment: Because of **aptitude** is a bit more complex, but it's also good.

Comment: I disagree... aptitude is rather more friendly since it offers to *graphically* manage a large bunch of packages (kind of what synaptic/packagekit/etc.) graphically from the command prompt. Also, is quite less prone to make mayor breakage to the package list.

Comment: @Braiam it's your think, not my